# How does StackOverflow provide a preview of markdown text, without causing lag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, markdown

I'm making a blog that takes markdown syntax. I would like to be able to provide an updated preview on every keystroke, just like Stackoverflow does when asking and answering questions. My current solution is incredibly laggy.

**How does Stackoverflow implement their solution to provide an updated preview of markdown text without causing lag?**

Currently, I make an AJAX call to the server on every keystroke in the `post-content` text area. The server sanitizes the content and returns HTML. The `preview` div is then updated with the new HTML:

```
$('#post-content').bind('input propertychange', (function() {
    var content = {"content": this.value};
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            $('#preview').html(data['content']);
        }
        ...
    });
 }));
```

This isn't working well. If I type at full speed, the text area ends up missing about 1/3 of my characters. My server is a tiny 500MB RAM VM. I'm not sure if the server is bottle neck, but I don't understand why the textarea would be lagging because of a slow AJAX call - it seems to me that this line is the bottle neck:

```
$('#preview').html(data['content']);
```

But I don't know enough about front end development to speculate on this.

Comment: most libraries can do it in the browser

Comment: *"Currently, I make an AJAX call to the server on every keystroke..."* Honestly? Yes, that's going to be a massive bottleneck. Not to mention the asynchronous nature of these calls.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the problem is that AJAX calls are terrible slow... But that's just a guess...

Comment: If you do want a server to handle this (though I don't know why that would be), you'd do better to do it in batches of characters. Also, you'd abort a previous request before sending another. But wanting realtime updates *and* server processing seems like conflicting requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> How does StackOverflow provide a preview of markdown text, without causing lag?

They store the text locally on your client browser, there is no server or database round-trip

This can be verified by inspecting the code

Comment: They use the server when you submit the text for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Bálint Agreed, yes agreed :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't send an AJAX call at every keystroke to the server! Make the preview use something client-side and only use the server when you submit the post/comment.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the AJAX call is what is causing your lag. I haven't exactly looked but I can promise you that StackOverflow is not making a server call each time to validate and give you a preview of the markdown. They are just using Javascript to do it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow renders the preview client-side, which is why some of the tags aren't sanitized. AJAX calls (especially lots of them) are not neccesary, because most computers can do it just as easily without the server's help.

If you notice, syntax highlighting is not triggered for a few seconds, because it is inefficient to do that every time a character is typed.

Answer (score 0):

*Currently, I make an AJAX call to the server on every keystroke*

I will not paraphrase other answers and comments that have said it was a bad strategy. That said, if you cannot move your rendering to the client side and if you are ready to lower your expectations in term of speed you can use this solution (mentioned by user1106925 in comments):

- define a timer of, say, 300ms
- each keystroke resets the timer
- when the timer does timeout, make the AJAX call to the server

That should drastically reduce the number of AJAX call. The user do not have to press a "render" button (he only has to stop typing) so it does modify your current UI.

This is the strategy that is used by [Compiler Explorer](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer) (though not with markdown).